# Architect commands with multiple targets cannot specify overrides

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm converting a library ([ng-app-state](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/ng-app-state)) to use the angular cli, now that [v6 supports libraries](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4#4786) (yay!).

When trying to run certain CLI commands it fails with an error like this:

```
$ ng test --source-map ng-app-state
Architect commands with multiple targets cannot specify overrides.'test' would be run on the following projects: ng-app-state-monorepo,ng-app-state
Error: Architect commands with multiple targets cannot specify overrides.'test' would be run on the following projects: ng-app-state-monorepo,ng-app-state
    at TestCommand.validate (S:\Programming\git repositories\ng-app-state-monorepo\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:91:23)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to put the library name first, and the options afterward. E.g.

```
# do this
$ ng test ng-app-state --watch=true --source-map

# don't do this
$ ng test --watch=true --source-map ng-app-state
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple apps than you can mention its name in the command as below.

`yarn test web  --code-coverage`

here web is app in angular project.